# Get Added Entity State Primary Key Asp.Net Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to create Change Tracker by overriding dbcontext SaveChanges() method.

I couldnt get primary key for entity when state of added.

How can we get added entity state when try to save ChangeLog.

DbContext overrided SaveChanges is like this:

```
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {

            var adddedEntites = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            foreach (var added in adddedEntites)
            {
                var entityName = added.Entity.GetType().Name;


                foreach (var prop in added.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var currentValue = added.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                    var id = new Guid();

                    ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
                    {
                        Id = id,
                        EntityName = entityName,
                        PrimaryKeyValue = null// how can I get pkey,
                        PropertyName = prop,
                        NewValue = currentValue,
                        DateChanged = now,
                        ActionType = "A"
                    };
                    ChangeLogs.Add(log);

                }
            }

return base.SaveChanges()
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the primary key is set in `base.SaveChanges`, you can get it after the call to thereof, e.g. (using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)):

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var addedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

    var result = base.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var added in addedEntities)
    {
        var idInfo = added.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
        var id = idInfo.GetValue(added.Entity);
    }

    return result;
}
```